# how I can get the domain extensions from UITextField?

Tags: swift, regex

I want to accept the users who're studying at University, so I need to only accept the email format as
studentname@inst**.edu** or
studentname@inst**.edu.tr**

how can I verify that by using regex or another method in Swift 5? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension String {
   func regex(_ regex: String) -> Bool {
      return self.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression) != nil
   }
}
```

```
let email = "blah_email@inst.edu"
email.regex(#"^[\w]+@inst\.edu$"#)
// If email is of the form: "(...)@inst.edu", it will return true
```